# Vue is returning vm as undefined whenever I try to access it

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following bit of code:

[image: img]

Which prints the following in the console:

[image: img2]

I've been bashing my head for a very long time, not sure where to go from here. It was working just fine when I pushed last. Then, I made some changes which broke it as you can see. To try to fix it, I stashed my changes, but I'm still getting this error.

---

Edit

```
search: throttle(live => {
  let vm = this;

  console.log("entered!!!");
  console.log("this", this);
  console.log("vm", vm);

  if (typeof live == "undefined") {
    live = true;
  }

  if (!live) {
    // We are on the search page, we need to update the results
    if (vm.$route.name != "search") {
      vm.$router.push({ name: "search" });
    }
  }

  vm.$store.dispatch("search/get", {
    type: vm.searchType,
    query: vm.searchQuery
  });
}, 500)
```

Comment: Can you post more code? the screenshot doesn't really tell us where you are in the Vue component. From what I can glean, there's a throttle function wrapping the `console.log` statements, and that's probably where your problem is.

Comment: what's in line 503 of search.js? your error seems to be originating there... also, it's better to post code than images

Comment: I'm not sure which other part I can show you. That's the beginning of the method invoked on keydown and that's where it breaks.. Also, I'm at a point in the git history where it was JUST working. Like.. what could be wrong? I cleared cache, restarted my machine..

Comment: @MikeK is this in the Methods section of the Vue Component?

Comment: Yes it is, I've updated the OP

Comment: @PabloAlbornoz line 503 opens up the part where I do `vm.$store.dispatch("search/get", {` (in the edit I just made)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `search` is in your `methods` it should not be using an arrow function as that will give you the wrong `this` binding.

Instead use:

```js
methods: {
  search: throttle(function (live) {
     // ...
  }, 500)
}
```

Here I'm also assuming that `throttle` will preserve the `this` value, which would be typical for implementations of throttling.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you. May I ask how I'd be able to use an arrow function in this way, then, if I need to do `let vm = this`?

Comment: @MikeK I don't understand the question. A key property of arrow functions is how they bind `this`. You cannot use an arrow function here and still get the correct `this` value. Incidentally, there's no need to use `vm = this` here, you can just use `this` throughout the method instead. There'd be no problem using an arrow function inside the method, you just can't use it to define the method.

Comment: I see, I understand. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment, I suspect this is a scoping issue.
Perhaps if you return the throttle function with the Vue component passed in, you might see better results:

```
search: function() {
let vm = this;

return throttle(live => {
      console.log("entered!!!");
      console.log("this", this);
      console.log("vm", vm);

      if (typeof live == "undefined") {
        live = true;
      }

      if (!live) {
        // We are on the search page, we need to update the results
        if (vm.$route.name != "search") {
          vm.$router.push({ name: "search" });
        }
      }

      vm.$store.dispatch("search/get", {
        type: vm.searchType,
        query: vm.searchQuery
      });
    }, 500)
}
```